# Simpler way to make multiple panels with controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on my first VB program. I have a form with a panel. I side that panel are a series of panels that open when a continue button is Clicked.

Like so:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles MyBase.Load

    'Main Panel Layout'
    pnlMain.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(5, 150)
    pnlMain.Name = "pnlMain"
    pnlMain.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(600, 525)
    pnlMain.BackColor = Color.White
    pnlMain.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    pnlMain.AutoScroll = True

    'Sub Panel Layout'
    pnlSub.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(610, 150)
    pnlSub.Name = "pnlSub"
    pnlSub.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(648, 525)
    pnlSub.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
    pnlSub.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    'Layout Step 1 Panel'
    pnlStep_1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(2, 2)
    pnlStep_1.Name = "pnlStep_1"
    pnlStep_1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(579, 100)
    pnlStep_1.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
    pnlStep_1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    'Layout Step 1 Label'
    lblStep_1.Location = New Point(230, 38)
    lblStep_1.Text = "Step l"
    lblStep_1.Size = New Size(137, 24)
    lblStep_1.Font = New Font(lblStep_1.Font.FontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Bold)

    'Layout Step 1 Button"
    btnStep_1_Cont.Location = New Point(502, 73)
    btnStep_1_Cont.Text = "Continue"
    btnStep_1_Cont.Size = New Size(75, 25)
    btnStep_1_Cont.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke

    'Create Instane of Base Panels'
    Me.Controls.Add(pnlMain)
    Me.Controls.Add(pnlSub)

    'Create Instances of Step 1 Controls'
    pnlMain.Controls.Add(pnlStep_1)
    pnlStep_1.Controls.Add(lblStep_1)
    pnlStep_1.Controls.Add(btnStep_1_Cont)

    'Create Button Events for Step 1'
    AddHandler btnStep_1_Cont.Click, AddressOf btnStep_1_Cont_Click

End Sub
Private Sub btnStep_1_Cont_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

'Layout Step 2 Panel'
pnlStep_2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(2, 27)
pnlStep_2.Name = "pnlStep_2"
pnlStep_2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(579, 100)
pnlStep_2.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
pnlStep_2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle

'Layout Step 2 Label'
lblStep_2.Location = New Point(21, 38)
lblStep_2.Text = "Step 2"
lblStep_2.Size = New Size(554, 24)
lblStep_2.Font = New Font(lblStep_2.Font.FontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Bold)

'Layout Step 2 Button"
btnStep_2_Cont.Location = New Point(502, 73)
btnStep_2_Cont.Text = "Continue"
btnStep_2_Cont.Size = New Size(75, 25)
btnStep_2_Cont.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke

'Create Instances of Step 2 Controls'
pnlMain.Controls.Add(pnlStep_2)
If pnlMain.Contains(pnlStep_1) Then
    pnlStep_2.BringToFront()
End If
pnlStep_2.Controls.Add(lblStep_2)
pnlStep_2.Controls.Add(btnStep_2_Cont)

'Create Button Events for Step 2'
AddHandler btnStep_2_Cont.Click, AddressOf btnStep_2_Cont_Click
```

End Sub

And so on...

This will have over 50 steps in it. Which will get rather messy and repetitive after awhile. Is there a way to create a class create the panels and place each one a certain amount of px from the top of the last one? and just call that class and have them come up.

Same for the rest of the controls could I create a class for them and just enter the parameters.

With the Labels and the buttons, some may have two or three buttons and up to four labels.

Thanx in advance

Rab

Comment: Probably your best bet is to create a user control for each step.  You add a user control to your project in the same way as you do a form and you design it the same way too.  Once you build your project, you use your user control in the same way as you would any other control, adding it to a form in the designer or creating it in code.  You could add all the steps at once but all those controls will likely slow the whole thing down.  I would suggest removing the user control for a step when that step is done and creating and adding the user control for the next step in code.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, you dont need to create a `class`, you just have to repeat the `panel class`

```
dim myPanel as Panel

for i = 0 to 20
    myPanel = new Panel
    myPanel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(5*i, 150*i) '' or set you grid as you want
    myPanel.Name = "Panel" & i
    myPanel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(600, 525)
    myPanel.BackColor = Color.White
    myPanel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    myPanel.AutoScroll = True
    me.Controlls.Add(myPanel)
next
```

Comment: This just makes a bunch at once how to i make them open on a button in the panel?